# Kotlin JS - string to number conversion?

Tags: kotlin

How to do String to number conversion in Kotlin JS app. I am Using the following code and having some trouble converting from the `HTMLInputElement` value to double.

```kotlin
fun c2f(self: Any) {
   console.log("Self object: ${self} ")
   val celsius = document.getElementById("celcius")?.getAttribute("value") as Double
   val fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32
   console.log("Fahrenheit value: ${fahrenheit} ")
   window.alert("Celcius (${celsius}) -> Fahrenheit (${fahrenheit}) ")
 }
```

- Also i am not seeing any `toDouble()` function on `String` class as in the case of JVM app.

Comment: There is `String.toDouble(): Double` function in stdlib on JVM (http://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/StringsJVM.kt#L410). Note that it is an extension function, so it is not in the `String` class. You can find it easily via the code completion. More on extensions: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question as this would be helpful for somebody.

You can use the kotlin.js top level parse functions for `string` <-> `Number` conversion.

```kotlin
fun parseInt(s: String, radix: Int = 10): Int
fun safeParseInt(s : String) : Int?
fun safeParseDouble(s : String) : Double?
```

Comment: I think it is a bug in Kotlin JS API - String.toDouble() must be available for all backends. Fill free to create a report.

Comment: @SureshG of course you can use these functions until KT-4497 not fixed, but `toInt`, `toDouble` etc are more kotlinish :)

Comment: Some possible implementations of `toDouble` You can find [here](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/1420905175/113810345976161206390486810857)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the String.toXXX() functions, e.g.

```
val n = "1"
val m = 2 + n.toInt()

val x = "1.1"
val y = 2.0 + x.toFloat()
```

etc.